# SQL join to multiple lines in table

Tags: sql, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I'm trying to find the correct join to use in this situation. Table A contains a series of unique (i.e. no repeats) IDs. Table B contains multiple measurements for each ID, including IDs that don't exist in table A. I need a combined table that contains all the data in table B for the IDs that are in table A with the non-matched data.

For example:

```
A               B                                 JOINED:
ID              ID  | count | date                ID  | count | date
-               --  | ----- | ----                --  | ----- | ----
001             001 | 512   | 01-Aug-2016         001 | 512   | 01-Aug-2016
002             001 | 123   | 08-Aug-2016         001 | 123   | 08-Aug-2016
003             003 | 2325  | 01-Aug-2016         002 |       | 
004             003 | 423   | 08-Aug-2016         003 | 2325  | 01-Aug-2016 
005             004 | 2     | 01-Aug-2016         003 | 423   | 08-Aug-2016
                004 | 76    | 08-Aug-2016         004 | 2     | 01-Aug-2016
                                                  004 | 76    | 08-Aug-2016
                                                  005 |       |
```

Comment: You'll get a lot more eyes on your SFMC questions over at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com), specifically with the [marketing-cloud](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud) and [query](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/query) tags.

Comment: You wrote ' including IDs that don't exist in table A', but your example and Gordon's answer below suggests the opposite (i.e. all IDs are in table A and a subset of them in table B). Could you please clarify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have exactly described the `left join`:

```
select a.id, b.count, b.date
from a left join
     b
     on a.id = b.id;
```

Comment: And this description is more correct than that pictures with circles you can find all over the internet with "SQL JOIN TYPES" search request.

Comment: I've tried to use the "left join" but it can only show 1 line of the count and date.

Comment: I finally figured out the issue as I used the id as the unique key. thank you so much.